# Any policies around Dead links?

Tags: discussion, editing, hyperlinks

I have been reviewing a lot of older posts (~10 years old) and there are quite a few with links that are either dead or links that point to sites that no longer contain the relevant information that the link was originally referring to.

In one case, I found a comparable site that contained the result the dead link cited and replaced the link in an edit. But in a lot of cases where someone is not citing a specific result, this is sometimes not possible.

**Should the 10-year-old question be edited to remove the dead link?** Is there any policy on the process to take when deciding on what to do with a dead or stale link? Surprisingly, I couldn't find an existing discussion on this. There is a small sub-discussion on this topic in this question:

[What to do with links to arXiv front end?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4516/what-to-do-with-links-to-arxiv-front-end)

As an example of what I encountered, this posting:

[edges minus vertices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40351/edges-minus-vertices)

has a link to a pdf document at:

http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1994.2/Main/icm1994.2.1375.1383.ocr.pdf

and while the link is not dead (it still goes to the ICM Math Union website) it does not find this pdf file it tried to cite. The question could potentially have this extra tidbit of information removed without affecting the message quality of the question.

Should there be a policy? Could I propose an edit that I feel makes the most sense? I wouldn't know if my decision is breaking any rules (written or unwritten) around editing.

Comment: One rule around editing old posts is, don't overdo it. Each edit bumps the old post to the front page, bumping some newer post off the page. Three or four such bumps a day is the maximum I'd recommend.

Comment: Sometimes dead links can be recovered via the Wayback Machine. For example, the Math Union pdf in your post can be found at https://web.archive.org/web/20170811094846/http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1994.2/Main/icm1994.2.1375.1383.ocr.pdf.

Comment: ... And then, once you know what the linked paper is, you can sometimes replace it with a current link: for example https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-0348-9078-6_132 (which in this instance is behind a paywall).

Comment: @jeq better is not a link.springer.com url, but a doi url, in this case https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-9078-6_132 (found in the "about this paper" section of the page). And there is still the IMU free copy of volume 2 of the 1994 proceedings: https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/ICM/Proceedings/ICM1994.2/ICM1994.2.ocr.pdf

Comment: I have edited [the question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40351/edges-minus-vertices) with a sample display of info and links one might want to include if editing to fix links

Comment: I would guess that at least *some* of the [posts linking to archive.org](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3a%22*web.archive.org*%22) have been edited to restore dead links, especially if you look [among recently active posts](https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22*web.archive.org*%22). Using SEDE you can find specific edits where [such links were added](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1177886/posts-where-some-text-missing-in-the-earlier-revision-was-added-including-the-ed?word=archive.org).

Comment: The first comment mentioned bumping too many posts, which was previously discussed here: [Do we have an unofficial quota on how many old questions one should bump for minor edits in a single day?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/599) Some recommendations on the way to link to papers was discussed, for example, here: [Edits with links to material under restricted access](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3193#3195).

Comment: Dead links are the reason for my inveterate [hostility to "here" and "this paper" links](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2383/lspice?tab=activity&sort=revisions).  If you say what your link is supposed to point to, then your link is still somewhat useful even if the target goes away.  (Even better is, as @DavidRoberts [says](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4721/any-policies-around-dead-links#comment24025_4721), to combine this strategy with links to URLs specifically intended to stay alive as long as possible.  I only learned to do that recently, and I still sometimes forget.)

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is this "bumping" feature of the software something we could make a feature request around?  I imagine being able to make a "bumpless" edit which requires  moderator approval.

Comment: @StevenGubkin There are already some feature requests related to this: [Minor edits, subject to review](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/192) on this meta. (See also some of the [questions linked there](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/linked/192).)
[Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122567) on [meta.se] (and [the linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/122567)).

Comment: (For anyone who doesn't follow all of @MartinSleziak's [references](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4721/any-policies-around-dead-links#comment24033_4721), [this](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4721/any-policies-around-dead-links#comment24031_4721) is an *extremely* oft-mentioned request, and has been for a long time, so it seems fairly likely that SE has no intention of implementing it.)

Comment: And it's not just a matter of SE being stubborn and resisting the will of the people – there are good and sufficient reasons for the bumping (as developed in those links).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess I usually act as follows:

a) If I know how to fix the link (typically, link points to an identifiable paper), I either edit  accordingly, or add the link as a comment (I might even provide 2 links, e.g., link to journal, often behind paywall, ideally using DOI, along with arXiv link); also I might add the journal reference when it wasn't initially.

b) If I don't know how to fix the link, I'll post a comment such as "the link is broken", with the hope that OP, if still active on MO, might fix the link. If not, still one can hope some other user knows how to fix/replace the link. At worst, it's useful that the reader is warned that the link is broken.

Anticipating on this, it's useful to check links and fix them before they become broken, for instance adding information that make them identifiable/retrievable, adding reference info, DOI. Also in case of external link to a picture, to embed the picture.

Comment: Yes, even just adding text giving a journal reference is preferable to link text that just says "this", with an opaque journal/publisher-specific url filled with numbers and letters.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's your policy for when to edit vs. when to add a comment?  I try to stick with a comment for questions that aren't already on the front page, but then that's only useful for people who think to check the comments on a years-old dead link.

Comment: @LSpice not sure of a very rational answer, but I'd take into account: whether there are other improvements to make to the post (e.g. formatting), whether the post is already bumped, and if not, whether I believe it's worth being bumped (i.e., of interest to readers), whether I already recently bumped posts; possibly also the fact adding a link in a comment will be more or less visible according to whether there are already many comments. (I don't think I often bumped a question just to update a link.)