# Updated: Is it time to replace links to the UCDavis arXiv frontend?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, editing, hyperlinks

[This question from March 2020](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4516/what-to-do-with-links-to-arxiv-front-end) points out that many questions/answers link to papers at the http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/ frontend instead of at the arXiv itself, but that the frontend had been down a few weeks.  There are c.600 affected questions and it looks like a large proportion of the links could be fixed by a simple search-and-replace; so comments and [the well-received answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4517/2273) suggested asking SE employees to do such a search-and-replace fix (moderators don’t have that ability), but felt “down for a few weeks” was too soon.

The frontend has now been down for 17 months; presumably this is no longer too soon.  **Can moderators now petition SE for a search-and-replace fix?  Or if that’s too administratively difficult, should we just fix the links by hand, trying not to bump too many at once as usual?**

Useful search queries, copied from the older question:

- [posts containing url:"*front.math.ucdavis.edu*"](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3a%22*front.math.ucdavis.edu*%22)
- [posts containing it that have recently been bumped](https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22*front.math.ucdavis.edu*%22).

Search-and-replace suggestion: The links fall into several groups, some that should be easy to recognise and fix by regex, others less clear.  Hopefully a large proportion can be fixed by regex, leaving the rest to fix by hand.

For links to preprints [after April 2007](https://arxiv.org/help/arxiv_identifier), the correspondence is straightforward — we want to replace a url like `http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0809.1179` with `https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.1179`, and the first four digits represent `YYMM`.  So a regex replacing `https?://front.math.ucdavis.edu/([12]|0[8-9]|071|070[4-9])` with `https://arxiv.org/abs/\1` should recognise and fix these links, I think.  (Details depend on the regex flavour used, of course.)

Links to older preprints are less consistent.  Some have the form `https://front.math.ucdavis.edu/math.LO/9909115`, and these should be easy again: the identifier part agrees with the arXiv’s, so a regex replace of `https?://front.math.ucdavis.edu/(math[.a-zA-Z]*/\d+)` by `https://arxiv.org/abs/\1` should recognised and fix these.  But others use a different identifier, whose correspondence with the arXiv’s identifiers seems unclear — e.g. `http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0310.5109` corresponds to `https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310109` (and `https://arxiv.org/abs/0310.5109` doesn’t work). Does anyone else know or see how the correspondence works for these?

Finally there are links to category searches, and the like, which I don’t think we can hope to fix by regex.  [This edit history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/132018/revisions) has examples of all three kinds.

Comment: You should add a suggested solution, e.g. a regex describing a good replacement strategy.

Comment: I will add that there are [248 comments with such links](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/556789/comments-containing-given-keyword-with-text-and-author?Word=front.math.ucdavis.edu). (If Stack Exchange would be willing to use some automated proces to change such links, they can probably do so also in comments, not only in posts.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I’ve added a regex suggestion which I think should get a large proportion of the broken links, and hopefully no false positives, although of course I haven’t been able to test/debug it on the full input set.

Comment: Thanks! With the status-review, I hope we'll attract the attention of some StackOverlords soon. I'll see if I can speed it up as well.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Are you sure that [this revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/132018/revisions) is an example you want? This seems to be link to a search rather than a link to and article in the "old format". I left a few more comment [in MO editors' lounge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10243/conversation/links-to-arxiv-frontend).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: The edit diff in that link shows three different kinds of example: one search link, which I don’t think we could hope to fix by regex; two of the post-April-2007 links that my suggested regex should fix; and two of the pre-April-2007 links that might or might not be regex-able.

Comment: My mistake. I thought that by "pre-2007" you mean links of the form similar to `https://front.math.ucdavis.edu/math.LO/9909115`.

Comment: Looking at only the posts (not comments) I count about 900 links. Of them, more than 250 start with 00-06. And about 60 start with 92-99. So I guess that there are at least 300 links where it's unclear how to transform them. @AsafKaragila Wouldn't it be better to contact SE staff only after we know how the URLs can be transformed? Or is the intention to find out whether this is possible *in principle* and to deal with the problematic parts later?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Right — the confusing thing is that for pre-2007 papers, the frontend seems to provide url’s in at least two different forms, some like the example you give, some like the ones in the edit history I linked.  For the ones in the edit history, the correspondence with arXiv’s url/identifier is totally unclear to me.  For examples like your form, the conversion is clearer — the identifier `math.LO` agrees with the arXiv, so we just need to change the url prefix — but it would take a little thought to write a regex that’ll recognise url’s of that form without false positives.

Comment: @Martin: The [status-review] puts the thing on their todo list, which is probably long enough that it will take a while. We absolutely should figure out the algorithm for replacing until then, though.

Comment: Maybe for some of them it is [removing .5 and adding /math](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243?m=58980247#58980247) and [replacing .47 by 0 and adding /math-ph](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58980879#58980879)? (But I only tested it on a few URLs.)

Comment: Shouldn’t the regex for post-2007 include numbers starting with 2 as well?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Thanks, fixed!  @ Martin: yes, from a few examples it looks like the system works something like that.  But at least for my part, I wouldn’t feel confident proposing a regex for a half-guessed system without being able to test the regex out a bit.  If you feel confident enough to add a regex to handle these then that’d be great!

Comment: Does somebody know whether [lanl.arxiv.org](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3a%22%2Alanl.arxiv.org%2A%22) is down only temporarily or whether all links to that domain should be considered dead, too? (This is not directly related to the front.math.ucdavis.edu, but it seems like a similar problem, so I thought that it might be worth mentioning.)

Comment: Just to note, Martin and I found yet another oddity. The arXiv front identifier "9612.5114" which I thought should be "math/9612114", really points to "dg-ga/9612014". So maybe `***.51** = dg-ga`?

Comment: Another weird data point. I think the link http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/9712.5188 should point to  https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9712048

Comment: Aha, I found the old FAQ posting where the Front explained the numbering technicalities https://web.archive.org/web/20060901072412/http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/ifaq#2.4: "Until March 2000, the Front renumbered articles in the old mathematical archives alg-geom, funct-an, dg-ga, and q-alg as math archive articles. To avoid duplicate numbers, the system added 50 to each funct-an number, 100 for dg-ga, and 140 for q-alg. Since this system was never adopted at the arXiv, it has for now been scrapped....

Comment: ....  If you use cite or link to any math articles math.XX/yymmnnn, where the year yy is 97 or prior and the number nnn is less than 200, you should convert back to the original numbers as stamped on the articles themselves."

Comment: @Asaf can we get the [status-review] back on this? We are probably in a position to have an automated solution applied. See [my answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5290/4177) for more details

Comment: Sorry for the noisy edits - the system (for an unknown reason) did not send this to our board for review when the status-review tag was added so I'm trying to force it to re-run.

Comment: @Slate Just to clarify - this change will be on MathOverflow only, right? AFAICT, nobody checked whether some of the posts on other sites contain the links before April 2007 - where simple replacement doesn't work. Moreover, number of posts on other sites seems to be small. (From search I got [277 results networkwide](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3a%22*front.math.ucdavis.edu*%22&pagesize=50) and [262 results on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3a%22*front.math.ucdavis.edu*%22).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I've clarified in the request that it should only be run on Math Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for raising this one to our attention. We've now executed the requested changes on Math Overflow. However, it looks like, given the work y'all put in, this change set is relatively issue-free, which is pretty fantastic. Still, as with all link replacements, we do expect a bit of routine cleanup work, so be on the lookout for any cases that look odd.

Let us know if you run into any major fallout as a result of the change and we'll see what we can do to help.

Comment: Thanks heaps to the team!

Answer (score 9):

As of 29 March 2022, I claim all the links in questions and answers to `front.math.ucdavis.edu` that predate April 2007, when the arXiv moved to the new, uniform identifiers `YYMM.NNNN[N]`, have been fixed, as well as every link to things with ids up to the end of 2007. This can be verified by checking the struck-through SEDE links to the various older categories in [Martin's answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5137/4177). This might also be verified by using fancier tools, like finding all mentions of the url string, but removing anything that's a comment, and anything where the arXiv id starts with 08, 09 or 1. There should only be the ≤14 posts with ids starting with 07, all of which are fixed, if any.

There are comments with links that point to the older link syntax used by the UCDavis Front, and (hopefully!) all of them are replied to pointing out a working link.

The remaining changes that need to be made are as follows, copied from [Martin's answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5137/4177):

---

> **Links which can be mass-converted**

> - Links where the id starts with 08 and 09 are after 2007, so they should be safe. SEDE returns [113 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/0%5B8-9%5D) and [34 comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/0%5B8-9%5D). ([SEDE - last activity](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1474696/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links-ordered-by-last-activity-of-the-question?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/0%5B8-9%5D), [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/0%5B8-9%5D))
> - Links where the id starts with 1 are after 2010, I got [208 posts from search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3a%22*front.math.ucdavis.edu/1*%22), [209 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/1) and [112 comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/1) from SEDE. ([SEDE - last activity](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1474696/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links-ordered-by-last-activity-of-the-question?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/1), [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/1))

---

Answer (score 8):

I've reviewed your request and - while I'd generally want to say "yes, we can do this" - in this case, I'm sorry to say that I don't think it will be possible - at least, not without some effort from you all first. I really do think it's important that the links on this site are functional, so I appreciate your bringing this up for discussion.

The tool we have to make this change is a pretty simple find/replace tool that only works for post content, not comments. It only works for URLs and it can't accept RegEx. So, I think you may already see the problem. While I really appreciate the effort that y'all went to to find the various treatments of the URLs, we can't even only update the ones that are an easy swap without changing all of the others since the content needing to be replaced is the same in all cases.

As you might also see, this doesn't mean that we can't ever do this - it means that we'd need you to help us out before we can. Based on the comments, it sounds like about 2/3 of the ~900 links are the "easy" first and second type. If that's the case, you could manually repair the remaining ~300 URLs first and we can use the link editing tool to fix the remainder of the links which, despite being in two formats require the same change to happen since arXiv helpfully automatically redirects to the correct URL.

So to put it in other words:

1. First you all work together to fix the outstanding links of the second and third type manually.

   - Based on a [comment from Martin Sleziak](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5124/is-it-time-to-replace-links-to-the-ucdavis-arxiv-frontend#comment26339_5124) it looks like there's about 300 links in the third category. It seems like correcting these links in an automated way may be difficult regardless since it's unclear how they should change.
2. Once the difficult URLs are fixed, we will bulk find/replace the remaining using the following method:

   - Find `http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/` and replace with `https://arxiv.org/abs/`

As far as I understand, we can not bulk edit all 900 URLs first as it will make the pre-2007 URLs even more "wrong" and may make them more difficult to find and repair at a later point in time.

If you can find a consistent way to convert from one of the pre-2007 URLs to the new arXiv URL, you may be able to have someone create a userscript to update these over time, a few questions per day but that's a big "if".

Please let me know if this is clear or if you have any other questions about this response.

Comment: As someone whose edit history will show his endless appetite for tidying, I would be happy to be part of such a manual effort, which presumably it would be unobjectionable to spread over time.  However, is there any way to do it without meaninglessly promoting hundreds of posts to the front page?

Comment: @LSpice Something like that was discussed several times, you can see various feature requests around this. (I still hope that this is going to be implemented at some point - but AFAICT, at the moment  there is no way to edit posts without bumping.) See also: [Minor edits, subject to review](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/192) (on this meta) or [Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122567) (on [meta.se]).

Comment: *The tool we have to make this change is a pretty simple find/replace tool that only works for post content, not comments. It only works for URLs and it can't accept RegEx.* You are a software company, so making new tools to interact with your main product should be a normal thing for you. And a regex find/replace engine is something that could have many other applications in additions to this task. I imagine it there are prioritization and cost/benefit issues here; "we don't have the tools to do that" surely is not the whole story.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni considering the vast list of things that need to be addressed, building a better tool for this specific issue is extremely low priority.

Comment: @LSpice I've been attacking them slowly, using the search tools in Martin's answer. It would be nice to divide the effort. Perhaps attacking the "Maybe manually, maybe mass converted" ones would be a good place to start, they could be knocked off over a week or so. The pre-2000 ones likewise. The ~200 posts with links from 2000–06 are going to be a slow slog. There may be some overlap, though, which will help—I've seen posts with multiple links from all over the shop.

Comment: @DavidRoberts, I definitely still want to help, although, as for everyone, the semester being underway cuts down dramatically on my MO time (hence my near-two weeks' delay).  Have you just been editing them as regular posts, in a way that bumps them to the front page?  (I understand that that is the norm, and know no better way, but wanted to make sure it was the appropriate way to proceed before diving in.)

Comment: @LSpice yes, I've been just doing a couple at a time, the normal way. Even just attacking one a day would be progress. The posts are spread over a wide range of topics, so it's not like fixing up a whole bunch on a niche topic and crowding the front page.

Comment: Meanwhile, the tool was apparently [significantly improved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367881/links-to-html-versions-of-rfcs-need-to-move-from-tools-to-datatracker/370325#comment1236999_370325). Does this change the answer in any way?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek No, it doesn't. The improvements made don't include regex - the main improvement was that we now can run the query across the network rather than per-site. CMs also have the ability to preview the impact of the changes before requesting the dev team makes them. Regex hasn't been added.

Comment: All right, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Catija we have made big progress on the manual edits, see [my new answer here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5290/4177) with a summary. This should be ready to be revisited by next week, if not before. The aim is to have only arXiv Front links from 2008 onwards outstanding and needing replacement. This is not a problem for a simple find/replace.

Comment: All the manual edits seem to be done, now. Time to revisit this one, if I may be so bold...

Answer (score 7):

As some of you may have noticed, I have a script which repairs broken links / images, with some more options than the [mass-replacement tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/295232) available to Stack Exchange staff. It can do all kinds of substitutions, checks if the new URL actually exists and if not, queries the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) for a snapshot.

I fed it the following rules:

```
    {
        "urlPart": "front\\.math\\.ucdavis\\.edu/(0[0-6]\\d{2})\\.5(\\d{3})",
        "status": "KNOWN_BROKEN",
        "replacements": [
            "arxiv.org/abs/math/$3$4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "urlPart": "front\\.math\\.ucdavis\\.edu/(0[0-6]\\d{2})\\.47(\\d{2})",
        "status": "KNOWN_BROKEN",
        "replacements": [
            "arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/$30$4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "urlPart": "front\\.math\\.ucdavis\\.edu/(\\d{4}\\.\\d{4})",
        "status": "KNOWN_BROKEN",
        "replacements": [
            "arxiv.org/abs/$3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "urlPart": "front\\.math\\.ucdavis\\.edu/math(\\.LO)?/(\\d{7})",
        "status": "KNOWN_BROKEN",
        "replacements": [
            "arxiv.org/abs/math/$4"
        ]
    }
```

I just did a dry run and [these](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/a6fdfac3a6d798f5de3155882a505344) are the replacements it would make. The first column is the number of posts the link appears in. I can't post the results here because the table is too large (an answer is limited to 30,000 characters).

The only link it cannot replace is `http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0309.3208` which appears in [number-theoretic congruences with geometry and topology?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/28087/70594).

When everything checks out, I can limit the edits it makes to posts which cannot be repaired by the mass-replacement tool; after all, my edits will bump posts to the homepage.

Comment: In case it is useful for some people reading this, I will add a link to a previous discussion on this meta where your script was brought up: [Are edits performed by external, non-SE robots allowed?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4057)

Comment: I found _a_ paper that one might think corresponds to the arXiv Front identifier `0309.3208`, namely https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309208, but the topic is wrong. It might be https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309108, but then I can't see how the identifier transforms. Looking at https://web.archive.org/web/20071012191626/http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/math.CO/0309, the paper `math/0309108` has url link containing `0309.5108`.

Comment: @DavidRoberts thanks. We shouldn't discount the possibility that the link was/is wrong to begin with ...

Comment: @Glorfindel True, but unexpected! I was surprised to see the 90s papers in your list, and then doubly so when I checked the progress I'd made on manual edits and saw I'd crossed off a bunch in that format!

Comment: I fixed the ones in answers with `front.math.ucdavis.edu/math` in the urls from my last comment. The _comments_ with links like this had been fixed by Asaf, and so in the bump of Martin's answer I'd missed that they weren't crossed off.

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this! It would have taken a lot longer, otherwise...

Comment: @DavidRoberts you're welcome, it was a pleasure. Thanks for your efforts as well!

Answer (score 6):

At this moment, it is unclear whether a project like this should be done. (After all, until we heard from people running the arXiv frontend, we still should count as a possibility that it will be running again at some point.)

Still, it might be useful to analyze a bit what would the scope of the project be - how many links would need manual editing, how many links can be mass-converted, etc.

I have started this CW answer - please do edit it if you have additional information that might be useful here.

**Resources**

- Sometimes even a [simple search on the main site](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3a%22*front.math.ucdavis.edu*%22) might give some information.
- SEDE queries for searching for a specific string (or regex) in [posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu) and [comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu). (If we use a bit more complex query, we can get the same list [with recently active questions on the top](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1474696/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links-ordered-by-last-activity-of-the-question?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu). In general, editing answer to a questions which has already been bumped for some other reason is better than bumping an old post.)
- List of links [from posts](https://msleziak.com/temp/MO/list2Posts.txt) and [from comments](https://msleziak.com/temp/MO/list2Comments.txt)
- Maybe it might be useful to look also at such posts that [have already been edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu).

Notice that the numbers listed below are about the status at the time when this answer was first posted - you can find how the counts have changed using the links given below and from the updates added to this post.

**Links which can be mass-converted**

- Links where the id starts with 08 and 09 are after 2007, so they should be safe. SEDE returns [113 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/0%5B8-9%5D) and [34 comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/0%5B8-9%5D). ([SEDE - last activity](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1474696/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links-ordered-by-last-activity-of-the-question?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/0%5B8-9%5D), [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/0%5B8-9%5D))
- Links where the id starts with 1 are after 2010, I got [208 posts from search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3a%22*front.math.ucdavis.edu/1*%22), [209 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/1) and [112 comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/1) from SEDE. ([SEDE - last activity](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1474696/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links-ordered-by-last-activity-of-the-question?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/1), [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/1))

---

<sub>(**DR:** I claim all the rest are dealt with.)</sub>

**Links which can be mass-converted**

- Ids starting with 0704 to 0709 can most likely be converted automatically. At the moment, we get <strike>[20 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/070%5B4-9%5D) and [8 comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/070%5B4-9%5D)</strike> (all replied to with a working link). ([SEDE - last activity](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1474696/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links-ordered-by-last-activity-of-the-question?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/070%5B4-9%5D), [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/070%5B4-9%5D))
- All ids starting with 071 are also after April 2007. Search returns <strike>[4 posts](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3a%22*front.math.ucdavis.edu/071*%22)</strike> (**DR:** I also gave doi links where possible). SEDE gives <strike>[4 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/071) and [one comment](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/071).</strike> (**DR:** this has a reply pointing out the updated link) ([SEDE - last activity](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1474696/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links-ordered-by-last-activity-of-the-question?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/071), [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/071))

**Links which have to be edited manually**

- All links starting with `front.math.ucdavis.edu/math/` followed by 00 to 06 were before 2007. SEDE returns <strike>[195 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/0%5B0-6%5D)</strike>. [SEDE - last activity](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1474696/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links-ordered-by-last-activity-of-the-question?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/0%5B0-6%5D), [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/0%5B0-6%5D)
- All links starting with `front.math.ucdavis.edu/math/` followed by 00 to 06 were before 2007. SEDE returns <strike>[63 comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/0%5B0-6%5D)</strike> (all replied to with a working link). [SEDE - last activity](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1474696/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links-ordered-by-last-activity-of-the-question?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/0%5B0-6%5D), [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/0%5B0-6%5D)
- Ids starting with 9 are before 2000. At the moment, we get
  <strike>[41 posts from search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3a%22*front.math.ucdavis.edu/9*%22), and from SEDE [43 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/9) and [12 comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/9)</strike> (**DR:** all of these comments have a reply pointing out the updated link and title of the paper) [SEDE - last activity](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1474696/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links-ordered-by-last-activity-of-the-question?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/9), [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/9)
- <strike>Ids starting with 0700 to 0703 are also before April 2007. SEDE returns [3 comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/070%5B0-3%5D)</strike> (**DR:** I have replied to these comments with updated links, paper titles and doi where available) <strike>and [8 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/070%5B0-3%5D)</strike>. [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/070%5B0-3%5D)
- <strike>The above includes also the link http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0208.5107v2 from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14219/why-do-littlewood-richardson-coefficients-describe-the-cohomology-of-the-grassma/14231#14231) which doesn't exactly fit the pattern. This seems to be the only instance of linking to the version number.</strike>
- <strike>The few instances where front.math.ucdavis.edu is used as a plain text (i.e., it is following neither `http://` nor `https://`) should be treated on case-by-case basis. SEDE: [posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=%5B%5E/%5Dfront.math.ucdavis.edu).</strike>  (**DR:** there is one remaining text instance that is not intended as a link, but as a mention of the arxiv front.) <strike>There are also [9 such comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=%5B%5E/%5Dfront.math.ucdavis.edu).</strike> (**DR:** I have gone through and replied to the offending comments with updated links in all cases, and added paper titles and also doi links to the published versions where available) [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=%5B%5E/%5Dfront.math.ucdavis.edu)
- <strike>There is [only one post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/325408) with `front.math.ucdavis.edu/abs/` ([search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3a%22*front.math.ucdavis.edu/abs*%22), [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/abs/)) - a single post can be dealt with manually.</strike>
- <strike>There are only a few posts [with `front.math.ucdavis.edu/q-alg/`](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3a%22*front.math.ucdavis.edu/q-alg*%22) - they can be dealt with manually. (A few have [already been edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/q-alg).)</strike>

**Maybe manually, maybe mass converted**

- <strike>Links with math.AG, math.AT, math.LO etc.: They probably can be converted automatically, but a separate replacement for each category would be needed. Considering the low count, maybe manual editing might be preferable. SEDE returns [27 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/math.)</strike> (**DR:** these have all been manually fixed, I took the opportunity to add more value by giving paper details and links to published versions and also fix other nearby broken links) <strike>and [6 comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/math.)</strike> (**DR:** all these comments have a reply giving the updated link and title of the paper.) [SEDE - last activity](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1474696/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links-ordered-by-last-activity-of-the-question?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/math.), [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/math.)
- <strike>6 posts with links to `front.math.ucdavis.edu/math/`: [search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22%2Afront.math.ucdavis.edu/math/%2A%22),</strike> [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/math/) ([SEDE - last activity](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1474696/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links-ordered-by-last-activity-of-the-question?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/math/), [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/math/)). <s>There are also [3 such comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/math/). (These comments are listed also [here in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60092536#60092536).)</s> Those comments have been [edited by Asaf Karagila](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60109472#60109472).

**Links not going to articles**

- Links to searches (again only a few, **DR:** only 9 left, all in comments. The intent of the links is clear from the surrounding text  or the search query itself, when it has not been responded to with updated info already - I think it is safe to ignore these for now): [SEDE - comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/search), <strike>[search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3a%22*front.math.ucdavis.edu/search*%22), [SEDE - posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/search)</strike>. [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/search)
- <strike>There might be some posts which link to the arXiv frontend homepage, such as this answer: [Most helpful math resources on the web](https://mathoverflow.net/q/2147#2164). That is the only one I get by looking for [posts containing `front.math.ucdavis.edu/"`](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/%22)</strike>
- <strike>Links to authors (there are only a few of them): [search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3a%22*front.math.ucdavis.edu/author*%22), [SEDE - posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/author). It seems that there are [no such links in comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/author).</strike> [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/author)
- Links to `front.math.ucdavis.edu/categories` - <strike>both [search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3a%22%2Afront.math.ucdavis.edu%2Acategories%22) and [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/categories) return [one post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2556/real-world-applications-of-mathematics-by-arxiv-subject-area).</strike> And there are [two comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1461823/comments-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/categories). (**DR:** these comments can be ignored, I think, they both appear in discussion with enough signposting where a reader would be able to figure out how to find the new page) [SEDE - already edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=front.math.ucdavis.edu/categories)
- Link to `http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/math` in the post: [Handling arXiv feeds to avoid duplicates](https://mathoverflow.net/q/686).

Comment: I have struck of a couple that needed only two post edits. We should be able to get some of the items here, with only a few posts each, cleaned up within a couple of days, then likewise clean up the list.

Comment: @Martin: I've fixed the comments for you.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You mean [these three comments](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2022/1/10), right?

Comment: @Martin: As one can guess. Seeing how the links there are now correct...

Comment: Down to 98 manual ones in questions and answers, now!

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thank you a lot for your ongoing effort!

Comment: Now only comments to deal with in the time 2000–06! They can be dealt with by replying with a link to the current arXiv url. There are also only a small number of 2007 links in posts and comments, which can be dealt with. Then we only have the time period 2008–2019 to fix. Can this indeed be done with a script? The arxiv IDs are completely uniform in this time period.

Comment: Big thanks to all who have been slowly chipping away at these!